# Idiomatic way to parse and navigate UTF-8 byte stream

Tags: unicode, utf-8, rust

I'm working on a lexical analyzer / tokenizer in Rust that needs to parse a UTF-8 input file (given as a `&[u8]`) into individual `char`s for parsing, but also has to keep track of the byte position within the file. At a later stage -- say when an error needs to be reported in the input -- I need to locate the offending character based on the byte and backtrack to find the relative position on its line.

What is a/the idiomatic way to parse a byte stream into chars (keeping track of byte position); and are there functions in the standard library that allow me to calculate how many trailing bytes follow or whether a byte is the leading or a trailing byte, or do I have to implement these myself based on the Unicode standard?

For example, something like:

```
// First to parse some input stream:
let input: &[u8] = "something";
for (chr, bytepos) in parse(input) {
    // ...
}

// Later to locate a character based on the byte position and
// use is_leading_byte() to step backwards and count the number
// of characters since the start of the line:
let chr: u8 = input[some_bytepos];
chr.is_leading_byte();
chr.is_trailing_byte();
```

Comment: [One question per question, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) and storing that into a `Vec` (`let everything: Vec<_> = input.char_indices().collect()`).

Comment: If you have a `&[u8]` that is UTF-8, you should make it into a `&str`.

Comment: Do you really need the exact byte position of each character? It seems like you might be better off knowing the byte position of the start of the line, then the Unicode character position within the line.

Comment: I would like to keep track of the characters using only one index (for efficiency reasons -- there are a lot of tracked locations kept in memory).

Comment: @Fabian: Just putting this here; in case you did not know. A `char` represents a Unicode Code Point, and it may take multiple Code Points to compose a grapheme (notably when diacritics are involved, but not only).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) solves both of my issues:

```
let input: &str = "something";
for (offset, chr) in input.char_indices() {
    // ...
}
```

And at a later stage, looking up a character and backwards-counting the number of preceding characters on the line can be done with [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_at):

```
let input: &str = "something";
let where: usize = 4;
let (left,_) = input.split_at(where);
for (offset, chr) in left.char_indices().rev() {
    if chr == '\n' {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Matthieu M. pointed out a caveat: Iterating and counting the Unicode Code Points does not necessarily correspond to what one would instinctively perceive as individual letters of script; this is due to the fact that multiple code points may make up a grapheme. [An example can be found in the documentation of `chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars).